# Go Back to previus page on Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, page-refresh

I am making a "**not available**" webpage. So, when a page is **not available** it will redirect to that page and I want the user to go back to previous page if he hits refresh. Is it possible to go back to previous page when the user hit refresh on the browser?

Comment: Why would you want the user to be pressing a button and have something they're not expecting happen? This is poor design choice in principle.

Comment: yes its possible

You just have to write key press event here

Comment: please give some more information

Answer (score 0):

May this code will work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
Document.location.reload(false)
var referrer =  document.referrer;
});

$(document).bind('keydown keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 116) {
       window.location = referrer;
    }
    if(e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey) {
       window.location = referrer;
    }
});
```

Comment: it didnt work, i go to a certain page, then type the not available webpage url and refresh the page but it didnt go back

Comment: Commenting Document.location.reload(false) and then try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's impossible to disable such browser functionality like hit "refresh " button/
Maybe you can prevent "f5 " or " Ctrl F5" 
Example:

```
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) e.preventDefault(); };
$(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
```

And if you want to go to the previous page, you can use 
window.history.back() or window.history.go(-1);

Personally, i think you can show a message " Not availlable " in this page and after some seconds you automatically go to previous page like

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window.history.back();

},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function goback()
    {
        window.history.go(-1);
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = goback;
```